# Isn't string.length actually a method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, class, v8, string-length

I would like to get a better understanding of what is actually going on when I find the length of a string. I tried looking on W3, ECMA, and at the V8 Ignition website but not much luck.

I keep reading that ***'JavaScript treats primitive values as objects when executing methods and properties.'*** But, I can't seem to find out how exactly this happens. If I call a method/property on a primitive which, I assume gets interpreted as an object by Ignition, doesn't the `String` class need to call a function at some point to iterate the string? I feel like `myString.length` should be called a method and `String.length` could **MAYBE** be called a property, depending on at which point the "property" is found and how it's found.

Basically, I don't understand why it's touted as a property if it doesn't seem to be inherent and has to be fetched/determined. That seems like a method to me (let alone the fact that string.length) isn't even a real thing and is interpreted.

Comment: It's computed when the string is initialized https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-properties-of-string-instances-length

Comment: It's easy to think of strings in Javascript as mutable and as such length should be a method, but when you do `var a = 'hello'; a += ' hello';` it looks like you can mutate a string, but what's actually happening is a new string has been created.  It's also the reason why doing `a[0] = 'H'`, does nothing, and string has no `splice`, only `slice` as the string is not mutable.  But saying this arrays are mutable and is has a property length too, but properties can have getters & setters so in some respects can have implicit methods..

Comment: TBH, this is an engine implementation detail. From JS perspective, you need to treat is as a property (something that you can read from/write to). The engine may do whatever it needs to underneath the hood to achieve this. If you have worked with C#, properties behave like methods that have get and set functions. https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_properties.php . Hope this helps! (Note: this is not saying that the engine is written in C#, just trying to explain the different paradigms of the word "property")

Comment: @AkshayaShanbhogue this seems to answer my question the best so far. I suppose my question at this point is: **if I don't type .length, does the string have a length property or not?**

 It seems to me, that most of the JS community accidentally tells other people that length is an inherent property of the string. However, this can't be the case as it must be converted at some point. However, if the conversion happens as soon as the variable is set to a string, the name property makes sense. If the string Object only obtains a length when called on myString.length, this sounds like a method.

Comment: `if I don't type .length, does the string have a length property or not?`  Yes, a string will have a property length, no matter if you access it or not.  Maybe your question is, `Is length a native type, attached to the string`,.. No, at some level it's a property getter, otherwise you could set the length of a string, internally of course this could just be a proxy to a stored value, or maybe a special case optimisation that the browser engine uses, `.length` certainly wants to be optimised due too `.length` in loops, I think I remember the V8 engine having special cases for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

I can see several issues here that can be looked at separately:

**1. From a language specification perspective, is something a method or a property?**

Intuitively, the distinction is: if you write a function call like `obj.method()`, then it's a method; if you write `obj.property` (no `()`), then it's a property.

Of course in JavaScript, you could also say that everything is a property, and in case the current value of the property is a function, then that makes it a method. So `obj.method` gets you a reference to that function, and `obj.method()` gets and immediately calls it:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = function() { console.log("function called"); return 42; }
var x = obj.foo();  // A method!
var func = obj.foo;  // A property!
x = func();  // A call!
obj.foo = 42;
obj.foo();  // A TypeError!
```

**2. When it looks like a property access, is it always a direct read/write from/to memory, or might some function get executed under the hood?**

The latter. JavaScript itself even provides this capability to objects you can create:

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "property", {
  get: function() { console.log("getter was called"); return 42; },
  set: function(x) { console.log("setter was called"); }
});
// *Looks* like a pair of property accesses, but will call getter and setter:
obj.property = obj.property + 1;
```

The key is that users of this `obj` don't have to care that getters/setters are involved, to them `.property` looks like a property. This is of course very much intentional: implementation details of `obj` are abstracted away; you could modify the part of the code that sets up `obj` and its `.property` from a plain property to a getter/setter pair or vice versa without having to worry about updating other parts of the code that read/write it.

Some built-in objects rely on this trick, the most common example is arrays' `.length`: while it's [specified](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length) to be a property with certain "magic" behavior, the most straightforward way for engines to implement this is to use a getter/setter pair under the hood, where in particular the setter does the work of truncating any extra array elements if you set the length to a smaller value than before.

**3. So what *does* `"abc".length` do in V8?**

It reads a property directly from memory. All strings in V8 always have a length field internally. As commenters have pointed out, JavaScript strings are immutable, so the internal length field is written only once (when the string is created), and then becomes a read-only property.

Of course this is an internal implementation detail. Hypothetically, an engine could use a "C-style" string format internally, and then it would have to use a `strlen()`-like function to determine a string's length when needed. However, on a managed heap, being able to quickly determine each object's size is generally important for performance, so I'd be surprised if an engine actually made this choice. "Pascal-style" strings, where the length is stored explicitly, are more suitable for JavaScript and similar garbage-collected languages.

So, in particular, I'd say it's fair to assume that reading `myString.length` in JavaScript is always a very fast operation regardless of the string's length, because it *does not* iterate the string.

**4. What about `String.length`?**

Well, this doesn't have anything to do with strings or their lengths :-)

`String` is a function (e.g. you can call `String(123)` to get `"123"`), and all functions have a `length` property describing their number of formal parameters:

```
function two_params(a, b) { }
console.log(two_params.length);  // 2
```

As for whether that's a "simple property" or a getter under the hood: there's no reason to assume that it's not a simple property, but there's also no reason to assume that engines can't internally do whatever they want (so long as there's no observable functional difference) if they think it increases performance or saves memory or simplifies things or improves some other metric they care about :-)
(And engines can and do make use of this freedom, for various forms of "lazy"/on-demand computation, caching, optimization -- there are plenty of internal function calls that you probably wouldn't expect, and on the flip side what you "clearly see" as a function call in the JS source might (or might not!) get inlined or otherwise optimized away. The details change over time, and across different engines.)

Comment: `Hypothetically, an engine could use a "C-style" string format internally`  But surely it would fail.  `'\0'.length === 1`  ->  `strlen("\0") === 0`. But like you say pascal strings make more sense anyway..

Comment: @Keith : Yeah, one of the challenges would be that you'd have to find a way to encode the end-of-string sentinel in a way that doesn't collide with what JS considers valid strings, so a simple null-byte (like C does it) wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Length is not a method, it is a property. It doesn't actually do anything but return the length of an array, a string, or the number of parameters expected by a function. When you use .length, you are just asking the JavaScript interpreter to return a variable stored within an object; you are not calling a method.

Also, note that the String.length property gives the actual number of code units in a string, rather than a literal character count. One code unit is 16 bits as defined by UTF-16 (used by JavaScript). However, some special characters use 32 bits which means that in a string containing one of these characters the String.length property might give you a higher character count than the literal number of characters.

Link:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

And also one fact length work very different with string.length from Array.length

```
let myString = "bluebells";
myString.length = 4;
console.log(myString); //bluebells
console.log(myString.length); //9


//--
let myArr = [5,6,8,2,4,7];
myArr.length = 2;
console.log(myArr); //[5, 6]
console.log(myArr.length); //2
```